# Incompatibilidade da versão firebase com a do google services

Tags: android-studio, firebase

> Error:(40, 0) All firebase libraries must be either above or below
>   14.0.0

O erro se resume a isso. Eu já tentei resolver ele de diversas maneiras. Nunca encontrei uma solução. Os erros iam mudando e cada vez mais eles apareciam, então decidi voltar ao início.

Meu Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

E o meu gradle app (onde está apresentando o erro):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sesi2018.sevenfuel"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0' //(sei que aqui tem erro pelo fato de ser 15.0.0 e lá em baixo ser de outras versões... mas como disse anteriormente eu voltei do início pois cada vez mais os erros apareciam)
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando uma versão muito antiga do Firebase e do Google Play Services.
Actualize as suas dependências no gradle da app:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
```